# PHPExcel, get long number from excel file as text

Tags: php, phpexcel

i am trying to read an excel file, that includes a phone number. When reading that cell, it returns it as a number instead as text. So instead of getting the phone number as 0012312345678 i get it as 12312345000
The phone numbers are all in the first column(A).

my code for reading that excel file is:

```
$retArray = array();
$Reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($file);
$Reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$objXLS = $Reader->load($file);
$objWorksheet = $objXLS->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestCol = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestCol = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestCol);
$cnt = 0;
$range = "A:A";
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++) {
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestCol-1; $col++){
        $objWorksheet->getStyle($range)->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode( PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT );
        $retArray[$row][$col] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
    }
    $cnt++;
}
$objXLS->disconnectWorksheets();
unset($objXLS);
echo "$cnt" . "|" . json_encode($retArray);
```

Comment: I am not known with working with excel and php, but try to get the number as int and then convert it to a string.

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:A3000')
    ->getNumberFormat()
    ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT); ? Or take a look at  `setCellValueExplicit`

Comment: @RST still the last 3 digits are replaced with 000. I tried it with 35799123456 and got 35799123000

Comment: If the number is stored in MS Excel as a float (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems), then there will be some loss of precision when converting it to show all the digits

Comment: Simply setting a cell datatype to string when it contains a float value won't automagically convert the value to a string or restore lost digits....so what datatype are the values in the actual MS Excel file that you're reading? Are they string or number?

Comment: @MarkBaker, it is as typed in excel. when i right-click on the cell, then select Format Cell, its show as General. What i think the PHPExcel is doing, is that it's rounding the number up. So if number is 35799123456, its converting it to 35799234500 for some reason

Comment: No! PHPExcel isn't rounding anything for any reason. What it may be doing is converting the value as a float for some reason - which would result in that loss of precision (given that the numbers are too large to be stored as 32-bit signed integers in PHP) - although it should treat a string read from Excel as a string and not try to perform any conversion (but only if the stored Excel datatype is a string)

Answer (score 12):

On the top of your php file paste:

```
ini_set('precision', '15');
```

This set has solve my problem:

return: 3.5410705883463E+14
realy value: 357888057644723

Comment: OMG! .. THANK YU :-* saved my life ^^

Comment: it doesn't help if my value has '000..' in the end... 111110000 is still 1.1111E+9

Answer (score 0):

just add space to integer to show full number like this:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount,$param.' ');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(30);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$totalRows = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->getHighestRow();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
            ->getStyle('A1:A' . $totalRows)
            ->getNumberFormat()
            ->setFormatCode(PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT);

May be help!
```

Comment: Please add some description for the solution you have posted.